# What is the outcome of "() => true"

Tags: c#

I'm reviewing another person's code and can't ask him... What does that line of C# code do?

Comment: what if the person who has written the code finds this question ;P

Comment: Why are you reviewing code that you do not understand? Seems a bit odd...

Comment: If he wants to read this code and understand it let make him!.. What is the problem?

Comment: The method call where this expression was used required a parameter of type Func<bool>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a lambda expression that takes no parameter and returns true. 
The equivalent anonymous delegate is:

```
delegate() { return true; };
```

Most likely the method requires a parameter of type `Func<bool>`, which is a generic delegate with the same signature as above code.

**EDIT:**

As noted by cdhowie, the above lambda can also be evaluated to an expression tree of type `Expression<Func<bool>>`.

Here's the equivalent expression tree:

```
var body = Expression.Constant(true);
Expression<Func<bool>> returnsTrueExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(body);
```

You can 'convert' it to an actual delegate by calling `Compile()`

```
Func<bool> returnsTrueFunc = returnsTrueExpression.Compile();
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, it will be equivalent to `delegate() { return true; }` when evaluated as a delegate.  It will evaluate to an expression tree when evaluated as an `Expression<...>`.

Comment: @cdhowie: i was already changing my answer. The first answer was just a raw placeholder, to be fast :-)

Comment: @VVS: Noted.  Don't forget about the expression alternative though.  :)

Comment: @cdhowie: Do you think that would help the OP?

Comment: @VVS: Maybe, I don't know.  If the expression is used in LINQ-to-SQL code or something else using `IQueryable` then yes.  Unfortunately, the OP has not provided us enough context to know which answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is a lambda expression that always return true. This is a delegate that has functionality similar to this method

```
bool Test(){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It may not always be a delegate.  For example: `Expression<Func<bool>> exp = () => true;`.

Comment: @cdhowie - That is true. It might be an expression as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The code reminds me of when you may want to stub or mock values in the early stages of creating unit tests.

You could have a class that has a method like:

```
bool result = SomeClass.RunSomeImportantProcess(Func<bool> process)
```

and in your tests you might want to do something as a stub like

```
Assert.IsTrue(SomeClass.RunSomeImportantProcess(() => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lambda expression which doesn't take any parameter but returns true. Whether its required or not, you would have to provide more info to determine.